# How to get emacs auto-complete to complete the functions from the included header files?

Tags: emacs, autocomplete, cedet

I have configured emacs for automatic code completion using [emacs auto complete](http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/AutoComplete). I mainly use C/C++. I cannot get auto-complete to complete the function name form the included header files. For example, say I included `string.h` and when I type say `strl`, it does not give `strlen` as a potential candidate. Is there possibly a way to set this up?

I tried CEDET but the smart completion in CEDET is too slow or I may have it set up incorrectly.

Thanks,
skr

Comment: Could you post the setup you have done for autocomplete? Also, is it not showing only from the standard libraries or from your library as well?

Comment: I installed autocomplete and made the following changes in the .emacs file:  `(require 'auto-complete-config)
(add-to-list 'ac-dictionary-directories "~/.emacs.d/ac-dict")
(ac-config-default)`. The completion works fine for the C/C++ keywords and the symbols in the current buffer. The auto completion doesn't work for any library - standard or otherwise.

Comment: The setup looks alright.  You would have to follow the manual as Bozhidar Batsov indicates.  If you have done all the installation steps as per the manual, go on to see if the installation passes all the checks listed there and on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [autocomplete-mode](http://cx4a.org/software/auto-complete/manual.html#ac-source-semantic) manual it has build support for completion from a semantic(a CEDET component) source. I urge to take a look at the manual, alternatively one can create a custom completion source.

Comment: I got the semantic component working with auto-completion. In the auto-complete-config.el file, I added `ac-source-semantic` to the fucntion `ac-cc-mode-setup()` and now it completes the structure and class members and the library symbols. However, the annoying part is that it takes atleast 7 - 10 seconds to complete, it does not do it while I type. This was the main  reason that I stopped using CEDET code helpers - not only it is slow, it freezes emacs for 5 seconds or so when it is doing some computation in the background. Any idea how I can speed up things with ac or CEDET? Thanks a lot

Comment: I have been using codeblocks for a long time. Recently I switched to emacs seeing its power. But it seems to me that development assisting in codeblocks is a very good. Very good auto completion, shows the function prototype while calling a function, good debugger etc. Definitely emacs offers a lot more features than codeblocks but I am not getting the same feel with emacs :(

Comment: This is the best article that I know of CEDET & C/C++ - http://alexott.net/ru/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html Unfortunately it's in russian, but with Google Translate you'll probably understand most of it.

Comment: @BozhidarBatsov There's the English version too: http://alexott.net/en/writings/emacs-devenv/EmacsCedet.html